# Error in compiling VB6 active x dll

Tags: vb6, activex

I have an Active X dll created in VB6.  I made some changes in the code and now when I am trying to compile it, it throws an error "Error Accessing the System Registry".Now I am not logged in to the machine as admin or in its group.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Windows 7?  If so, the User Account Control (UAC) is preventing the build. When you launch Visual Studio 6, first right click on the icon and choose to run as administrator. This should resolve your problem.

Comment: If you don't have admin rights you will have a very hard time running a COM based development environment. VB6 is not supported on Windows 7 but most of the functionality will continue to work if you have admin permissions. The exception being IIS Web Applications in VB6 which do not work at all in Win 7+.